# Primefaces: the commandButton inside the rowexpander not perform the action at first click

Tags: primefaces, commandbutton, rowexpansion

I have a problem on a page with primefaces framwork, this is my fragment code:

```
            <p:rowExpansion rendered="#{riepilogoExtra.approvato == '0'}" >   
                <p:panelGrid columns="3" style="width:50px; border: 0px" >                            
                    <h:outputText value="Ore" />
                    <h:outputText value="Minuti" />
                    <h:outputText value="Note" />
                    <p:inputText id="QTA_MASSIMAHH" value="#{riepilogoExtra.qtaMassimaHH}" size="1" />
                    <p:inputText id="QTA_MASSIMAMM" value="#{riepilogoExtra.qtaMassimaMM}" size="1" />                        
                    <p:inputTextarea id="NOTE" rows="2" cols="20" value="#{riepilogoExtra.note}" /> 
                </p:panelGrid>     
                <p:commandButton 
                        ajax="true"
                        id="update" 
                        value="Salva" 
                        update="@form" 
                        action="#{riepilogoExtraResponsabileManagedBean.update(riepilogoExtra)}" 
                        icon="ui-icon-check" 
                        styleClass="ui-priority-primary" />

            </p:rowExpansion>
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow may you please specify what problem do you face?

Comment: Have you wrapped a `<h:form>` around your code?

Comment: the code is inside <h:form>

Comment: only special fields riepilogoExtra.qtaMassimaHH and riepilogoExtra.qtaMassimaMM are noted in the entity class with the notation @Transient

Comment: removing fields riepilogoExtra.qtaMassimaHH and riepilogoExtra.qtaMassimaMM it works fine

Answer (score 0):

hy,

if you have the problem for button don't work in the first click you must verify your console javascript you have error, resolve the problem and all is ok :)

Comment: there are no javascript errors 
The problem seems to be due to the fact that the first click make the selection while the second action